# WS2812 Strip Connector

Tags: led, led-strip, ws2812b

I'm trying to buy connectors for WS2812b LED strips. I have already found the item on eBay, but cannot find it on Digikey as Digikey has a gazillion of connectors.

The connector I am looking for looks like this, with three pins. Does anyone know what these connectors are called?

[image]